# REQUEST_URI redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, request-uri

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} team
RewriteRule ^ http://sitename.co.uk/about? [L,R=301]
```

The code above works perfectly if the url is /team/

BUT

if the URL is /team/john-smith/ I do not get redirected?

I can't figure out why this wouldn't work! Any ideas??

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a wordpress site, team is the post type and then it contains posts of team member names

Comment: ok then keep `RewriteRule ^team http://sitename.co.uk/about? [L,R=301,NC,NE]` as the first rule below `RewriteEngine On` rule and test from a new browser. Make sure there are no caching plugins in WP

Comment: I get this Error in browser:

`sitename.co.uk redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule with `THE_REQUEST` as your top rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} team [NC]
RewriteRule ^team http://sitename.co.uk/about? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing or completely clear browser cache.